# Sanitazing user uploaded (image) files for malicious / harmful content

Tags: php, image, security, file-upload, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image sanitization library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196351/image-sanitization-library)

How can a social web application that allows user file uploads, prevent harmful content hidden/stored in user files. I use php as a server side technology for a site. Users can upload images. Is there a way that the contents of these files can be verified via php? The images may also be downloaded by the owner and other users.